# Append rows to table via Sybase Load statement

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-iq

I used two consequent LOADs into a Sybase table via the below SQL script code.
But when loading the second file, it instead of appending it overwrites the raws.
Is there any option to avoid the overwrite?

```
LOAD TABLE Departments
( DepartmentID, DepartmentName, DepartmentHeadID )
FROM '/d1/MILL1/dept1.txt'
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your correctly, you got both files available at the moment you are doing the load. So you could do something like:

```
LOAD TABLE Departments
( DepartmentID, DepartmentName, DepartmentHeadID )
FROM '/d1/MILL1/dept1.txt','/d1/MILL1/dept2.txt';
```

Comment: Yes, this might be ok. But what if i want to load later any other file in the table, how to append and not overwrite?